# jQuery variable to php variable

Tags: php, jquery, highcharts

i have a problem when it comes to retrieving value from jQuery to php.i was able to get the value of my select and pass it to my php but i can't pass it back to php.
here is the code...

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $("select#months").change(function(event)
    {
        var m=$(this).val();
        alert(m);
    });
});
    </script>   

    <div>
    <select id="months">
      <option value='00'>Month...</option>
          <option value='01'>Jan</option>
          <option value='02'>Feb</option>
          <option value='03'>Mar</option>
          <option value='04'>Apr</option>
        </select>
        <select id="years">
        <?php
         for($yr=10; $yr<=$year; $yr++)
    {
        echo "<option value='".$yr."'>".$years[$yr]."</option>";
    }
    ?>
       </select>
    </div>
```

now i have to get the m variable from the jQuery code and echo it on my php.

Comment: Why do you have highcharts tag here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to post or get the page again, passing "m" as a parameter and reading it inside php.

Php and jquery can communicate with each other only using http posts/gets, cause they run on two different computers (php on your server, jquery on your users browser)

Unfortunately, to answer this question completely would mean teaching client-server from the basics.

Comment: i already did that but it wasn't working at all so i erased my code.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery code will run on your user's browser. You need to send *m* via **POST** (or GET) to your PHP script upon change.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
  {
    $("select#months").change(function(event)
    {
        var m=$(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "http://example.lan/your.php",
            data: {m: m},
            success: function(){alert("updated")}
        });
    });
});
```

and on your **PHP** code, do something about *m* if it is set:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['m'])) {
  // do stuff with M here 
}
?>
```

Comment: sorry.i'm really new with jQuery so i'm not really familiar with its functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

PHP and Javascript may appear in the same file, but they are far from being executed by the same machine. For example, take this simple script :

```
<?php

$foo = "Hello world!";

?>
<div id="mydiv"><?php echo $foo; ?></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() { alert( $('#mydiv').text() ); });
</script>
```

When you access this script from your browser, the server actually only parse this :

```
<?php

$foo = "Hello world!";

echo $foo;
```

Because everything else is *not* PHP, thus not processed by the engine (skipped at parsing time). Therefore, the document that is uploaded by the server to your browser is

```
<div id="mydiv">Hello world!</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() { alert( $('#mydiv').text() ); });
</script>
```

As you see, at this point, there is no PHP at all in what's outputted by the server (what is received by the client), so there is no way that you can reference anything PHP at that point. The only way you can do this is by calling the same script again! (or any other PHP script)

PHP may receive parameters from external sources via `$_GET` and `$_POST`. Thus, modifying our code would be like

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['foo'])) {
    $foo = $_GET['foo'];   // we received our param like 
                           // '?foo=Hi!` from the HTTP request
} else {
    $foo = "Hello world";
}

?>
<div id="mydiv"><?php echo $foo; ?></div>
<form action="" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="foo" value="" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() { alert( $('#mydiv').text() ); });
</script>
```

And you can communication in both directions. For XHR with jQuery, there is no need to send a whole bunch of HTML with the query, we need to modify the source a little:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['foo'])) {
    echo "Message got : " . $_GET['foo'];
    exit;   // do not execute any more code from now
} else {
    $foo = "Hello world";
}

?>
<div id="mydiv"><?php echo $foo; ?></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() { 
      alert( $('#mydiv').text() );
      // note : assuming the code is in file "example.php"
      $.get('example.php', {foo: "Hi!"}, function(data) {
         alert(data);     // will show "Response got : Hi!";
      });
   });
</script>
```

In the last example, the file is parsed and processed twice by the server, the code is actually executed in this order :

1. the browser makes a first query to the PHP script
2. the server parse the file and sends the HTML,
3. the client receives the HTML
4. the Javascript code is executed

   - alert : "Hello world!"
   - create and send a GET XHR with parameter `foo=Hi!`
5. the server receives another request and parse the file

   - the `$_GET['foo']` argument is found
   - echo "Response got : Hi!"
6. the client receives the XHR response and invoke the callback function

   - alert : "Response got : Hi!"

Now, this last example may seem a bit more complicated, but really as simple as the other code :

```
<?php

$dataFile = 'data.txt';

if (isset($_POST['text'])) {
    file_put_contents($dataFile, $_POST['text'];
    echo "Saved!";
    exit;

} else if (file_exists($dataFile)) {
    $text = file_get_contents($dataFile);

} else {
    $text = '';
}

?>
<a id="lnkSave" href="example.php">Save</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var text = '<?php echo addslashes($text); ?>';
   $(function() {
      $('<textarea></textarea>').attr('id', 'text').appendTo(document).val(text);
      $('#lnkSave').click(function() {
          $.post($(this).attr('href'), {text:$('#text').val()}, function(data) {
              alert(data);
          });
      });
   });
</script>
```

I'll let you figure this one out; what it does and how it works.